# Weierstrass Substitution $\int\frac{1}{2+4\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I want to calculate $\int\frac{1}{2+4\sin(x)}$, and I know that I need to define:

$t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ which means that $\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\sqrt\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$, but I do not understand why.

I have tried searching about it, and I read about Weierstrass Substitution, but didn't understand its proof.

Can someone please explain me this equality?

I have also tried: $x=\arctan(t)$ and $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$, but I didn't know how to continue...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: set $z=\frac{x}{2}$ for short. You set $\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}=\tan z=t$, so $$t^2=\frac{\sin^2z}{\cos^2z}=\frac{\sin^2 z}{1-\sin^2z}$$(I used the identity $\cos^2z+\sin^2z=1$), so you have$$\sin^2z=t^2(1-\sin^2z)\rightarrow (1+t^2)\sin^2 z=t^2\rightarrow \sin^2z=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do $t=\tan\left(\frac x2\right)$ then, since $\frac{\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x/2)}=t$ and $\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)=1$, a simple computation shows that$$\sin\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac t{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\quad\text{and}\quad\cos\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}.$$But then$$\sin\left(x\right)=2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\cos\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$and$$\cos\left(x\right)=\cos^2\left(\frac x2\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$and therefore, and since $\mathrm dx=\frac2{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt$, your integral becomes$$\int\frac1{2+4\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}\frac2{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: You did! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While @JoséCarlosSantos's answer has explained how to show $\sin\tfrac{x}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\tfrac{t^2}{1+t^2}}$, for this problem writing $\sin x$ in terms of $t$ is more helpful. Note$$\sin x=2\sin\tfrac{x}{2}\cos\tfrac{x}{2}=\frac{2\tan\tfrac{x}{2}}{\sec^2\tfrac{x}{2}}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$This approach has the advantage we don't have to worry about $\pm$ signs from square-rooting in $\sin\tfrac{x}{2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\tfrac{x}{2}}$. Instead we can proceed to$$\int\frac{dx}{2+4\sin x}=\int\frac{dt/(1+t^2)}{1+2\sin x}=\int\frac{dt}{1+4t+t^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I believe that $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{cos(x)}$, but why is it equals to $1+\tan(x)$?

Comment: @MathLover I'll make my calculation more explicit so you can see why it's right:$$\sin x=2\tan\tfrac{x}{2}\cos^2\tfrac{x}{2}=\frac{2\tan\tfrac{x}{2}}{\sec^2\tfrac{x}{2}}=\frac{2\tan\tfrac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\tfrac{x}{2}}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately I do not familiar with $\sec(\alpha)$, and I do not understand why is $\sec^2(\alpha)=1+\tan^2(\alpha)$, thanks!

Comment: Oh Ok, I figured it out I think :)

Comment: Is there an easy way to solve $$\int\frac{dt}{1+4t+t^2}$$? I took me about half a page of writing to finish it... $t^2+4t+1 = (t+2)^2-3 = -3(1-\frac{1}{3}(t+2)^2=-3(1-(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(t+2))^2$ and than I defined $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(t+2)$, so from there I got:
$$- \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \int \frac{1}{(1+v)(1-v)}=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt3} (\int \frac{1}{1+v}dv+ \int \frac{1}{1-v}dv) $$, and from there it took a while to make it look nice... Thanks!

Comment: @MathLover Use $(t+2)^2=3\sec^2u$ so $t^2+4t+1=3\tan^2u$, i.e. take $t=\sqrt{3}\sec u-2$. By the same logic, $t=\sqrt{3}\cosh v-2$ is also an option.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not familiar with those functions...